# How to use includes in logstash conf files?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

Can includes be used in logstash config files?

**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example**

Can I replace this...

*file: beats.conf*

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
filter {
    date {
        match => ["myTimestamp", "yyyyMMdd_HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
        target => "date_time"
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
  }
}
```

...with this?

*file: date.inc*

```
date {
    match => ["myTimestamp", "yyyyMMdd_HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
    target => "date_time"
}
```

*file: beats.conf*

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
filter {
    #include <date.inc>  // <- THIS THIS THIS THIS THIS
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no support for "include" and Logstash is not able to load a pipeline splitted in different files in order to reuse common parts.
**EDIT:** The only way to compose a pipeline from different file is to specify a folder or wildcard "*" in the `path.config` setting so that config files are read in alphabetical order (Thanks to @Badger).

If you don't want to define your own pipeline's composition/compilation system, you could take a look on "Pipeline-to-Pipeline" communication that can be used for example to break-up you complex pipelines and reuse your filters on different flows: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/pipeline-to-pipeline.html. Note that with this approach you will pay the overhead of running multiple pipelines.

For example:

**pipelines.yml**

```
- pipeline.id: input
  path.config: "<path-to-file>/beats.conf"
- pipeline.id: date-filters
  # This common pipeline allow to reuse the same logic for complex filters
  path.config: "<path-to-file>/date.conf"
- pipeline.id: output
  path.config: "<path-to-file>/elasticsearch.conf"
```

**beats.conf**

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
output { pipeline { send_to => [commonFilters] } }
```

**date.conf**

```
input { pipeline { address => commonFilters } }
filter {
  date {
    match => ["myTimestamp", "yyyyMMdd_HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
    target => "date_time"
  }
}
output { pipeline { send_to => [output] } }
```

**elasticsearch.conf**

```
input { pipeline { address => output } }
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It is incorrect to say that Logstash is not able to load a pipeline splitted in different files. You can point path.config at a wildcard and it will load all the matching files as part of the same pipeline.